# How can I synchronize my app with iCloud?

Tags: cosmicmind

I have an issue with my app when I try to synchronize my app with Graph library with iCloud. I have follow the Graph instructions, "To connect Graph to iCloud, setup the iCloud entitlements with the iCloud" but not working for me. What can I do?? I also activate iCloud in the tab iCloud capabilities, without Key Value Coding, iCloud Documents and CloudKit enabled.

Please, explain me how can I resolve this and what can I wrong.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [Graph iCloud](http://www.cosmicmind.io/graph/icloud). Thank you!

Comment: Thanks so much .